# Using Pandas to computer frequency and count records

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Worker': ['A','A','B','B','C','D','D'],
                    'Task': ['T1','T2','T1','T3','T4','T1','T5'],
                    'Hour': [1,2,1,2,3,1,4]
                   })
```

The output is

```
  Worker Task  Hour
0      A   T1     1
1      A   T2     2
2      B   T1     1
3      B   T3     2
4      C   T4     3
5      D   T1     1
6      D   T5     4
```

I want to have table as below:

```
       Staff   Hour
Task     
 T1        3      3
 T2        1      2
 T3        1      2  
 T4        1      3
 T5        1      4
```

How could it be done? Thanks.

**[Edit: Solution from @ayhan but with updated requirement]**

```
df2.groupby('Task').agg({'Worker': 'size', 'Hour': 'sum'})
```

However, I have just realized that I do not count (i.e., size) the occurrence of 'Worker' but determine number of unique workers per task.

I have modified the DataFrame as follow:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Worker': ['A','A','B','B','C','D','D'],
                    'Task': ['T1','T1','T2','T3','T4','T2','T2'],
                    'Hour': [1,2,1,2,3,1,4]
                   })
```

The output is

```
  Worker Task  Hour
0      A   T1     1
1      A   T1     2
2      B   T2     1
3      B   T3     2
4      C   T4     3
5      D   T2     1
6      D   T2     4
```

And the desired output is

```
       Staff   Hour
Task     
 T1        1      3
 T2        2      6
 T3        1      2  
 T4        1      3
```

Comment: `df2.groupby('Task').agg({'Worker': 'size', 'Hour': 'sum'})`

Comment: You can change `size` to `nunique` if you want the number of unique workers (`df2.groupby('Task').agg({'Worker': 'nunique', 'Hour': 'sum'})`).